# Do these two prepositions mean the same thing? “You have got until/to the count of five”

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> You have got until the count of five

> You have got to the count of five

Do these two mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do mean the same thing.  In this case, "to" is being used in the same manner as "until".

> **to** *(preposition)* Expressing a point reached at the end of a range or after a period of time.
>   
> <sub>SOURCE: [Oxford Living Dictionaries "to"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to)</sub>